# How To Make A Button To Add Different Numbers To A Value Every Time It Is Click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, basic

In Visual Basic, I wanted to add 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 to my value "a" every time a button is clicked, i tried Select Case but there are two problems first, is that no matter what, it starts with 0, ok i set my default value to 0 --> "Dim a As Integer = 0" but when i first click the button, it should add 1 to that but it adds 0 and the second time i click the button then it add 1 and so on.

The second problem is that it goes until case 4 and stop there, it doesn't add the rest of them when clicked, its like 0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 7 and then no action after button click.

maybe I shouldn't use select case at all!

so if guys know any solution or other method to make it work ill be happy to know, thanks.

this is my source:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Label1.Text = (Str(a))

        Select Case a

            Case 0
                a += 1
            Case 1
                a += 2
            Case 2
                a += 4
            Case 3
                a += 8
            Case 4
                a += 16
            Case 5
                a += 32
            Case 6
                a += 64

        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the 2. problem this is because you do not have a case for `7`, thus nothing is done. You can include `Case Else` at the end of the code, then the code will go there, if the value is `7` or anything else, which is not amongst 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 6.

```
    Select Case a

        Case 0
            a += 1
        Case 1
            a += 2
        Case 2
            a += 4
        Case 3
            a += 8
        Case 4
            a += 16
        Case 5
            a += 32
        Case 6
            a += 64
        Case Else
            a + = 128
    End Select
```

Comment: I did as you said and now, it jumps from case 1 to 3 and the from Case 3 to Case 7 or Else Case 1->3->11->139

Comment: @hadiBastanfar - exactly. Once it is more than 6 it will always go to case Else.

Comment: but want it to go as ordered

Comment: it should go like this 1 -> 3  -> 7 -> 15 -> 31 -> 63 -> 127

Answer (score 0):

Your case values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) represent the number of the step (or the click count of the button), but you check the value of "a", which contains your result.
So, if you click your button the first time a = 0, so the code in `Case 0` gets executed. After that "a" results in 1.
When you click the button the second time a = 1, so `Case 1` gets executed and "a" results in 3 after that.
On the third click `Case 3` gets executed and "a" results in 11.

So, you either change your case values to 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, ... or you create a second variable (let's call it "b"), check for "b" in your select (`Select Case b`) and raise b by 1 every time the button got clicked.